# Wrong cipher suite or no connection with OpenSSL server

Tags: c++, openssl, server

generated key

> openssl ecparam -param_enc named_curve -name secp521r1 -genkey -outform PEM -out key.pem

generated cert

> openssl req -x509 -new -key key.pem -keyform PEM -out ca.pem -outform PEM -days 3650

when i use

```
openssl s_server -accept 5000 -key key.pem -cert ca.pem -tls1_2 -www
```

i can connect fine using

```
openssl s_client -host 10.8.0.26 -port 5000
```

Client tells me it uses

> Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>       Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

exactly what i want

when i compile and use the following c code to start the server

compiled with

> g++ Main2.cpp -ldl -lcrypto -lssl -o Main)

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>

#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

using namespace std;

void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{   char buf[1024];
    char reply[1024];
    int sd, bytes, err;
    const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

 err = SSL_accept(ssl);

    if ( err <= 0 ) {    /* do SSL-protocol accept */
        printf("%d\n",err);
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
 }
    else
    {
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
        if ( bytes > 0 )
        {
            buf[bytes] = 0;
            printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
            sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   /* construct reply */
            SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply)); /* send reply */
        }
        else
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
    close(sd);          /* close connection */
}


int OpenListener(int port)
{   int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
 

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));

 inet_aton("10.8.0.26", &addr.sin_addr);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    //addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    
 if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        perror("can't bind port");
        abort();
    }
    if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )
    {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

 //SSL_library_init();
 SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms(); 

 cout << SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION) << endl;

 SSL_CTX *ctx;
 const SSL_METHOD *method;

 method = TLSv1_2_server_method();
 //method = SSLv23_server_method();

 ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
         
 if (SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1) != 1)
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

 //if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384") != 1)
  // ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

 if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "ca.pem", "key.pem") != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

 if (SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx) != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

 if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "ca.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

 if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

 if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }



 int server;

 server = OpenListener(5000);

 struct sockaddr_in addr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL *ssl;

        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);  /* accept connection as usual */
        printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              /* get new SSL state with context */
  if (ssl == NULL) {
  
   ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
   return 0;
  
  }

    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);      /* set connection socket to SSL state */
        Servlet(ssl);         /* service connection */
  
    close(server);          /* close server socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);         /* release context */

    return 0;

}
```

when i now connect using openssl s_client just like above it uses

> Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>       Cipher    : ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

not ECDHE ! Why ?

When i use chrome/firefox to connect either to the openssl s_server or my server code i get:

> 140675163166384:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1396:

Why no connection at all ?

Comment: I am using OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015 i check this by printing it at the beginning of the code using cout << SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION) << endl;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server with ECDHE key and cert not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057280/server-with-ecdhe-key-and-cert-not-working).

Answer (score 2):

> when i now connect using openssl s_client just like above it uses
> `Protocol : TLSv1.2 Cipher : ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`
>
> not ECDHE ! Why ?

`ECDH` and `ECDHE` are two different Diffie-Hellman's. `ECDH` uses a fixed server key. `ECDHE` is ephemeral, and it uses a temporary key. You should be using `ECDHE`.

For `ECDHE`, you did not set the ECDHE callback with `SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh_callback`.

See [Server with ECDHE key and cert not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30057280) for details.

---

Related, here are the EC based DH ciphers:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!aNULL' | grep ECDH
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

---

> When i use chrome/firefox to connect either to the openssl s_server or
> my server code i get: `140675163166384:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1396`
>
> Why no connection at all ?

You used P-521. It should be supported, but it may be cause trouble. For maximum interoperability, use P-256: `... -param_enc named_curve -name secp256k1`.

---

The elliptic curve gear is available in TLS 1.0 and above. From [RFC 4492, Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) Cipher Suites for Transport Layer Security (TLS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492):

> This document describes additions to TLS to support ECC, applicable both to TLS Version 1.0 [2] and to TLS Version 1.1 [3]...

You should change this:

```
method = TLSv1_2_server_method();
```

To:

```
method = SSLv23_method();
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
...

const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
```

That gets you "TLS 1.0 and above", and it removes compression, which leaks information. You should also consider other server side options, like [`SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG).

TLS 1.2 in the only protocol version that provides the Authenticated Encryption, like AES/GCM. But you usually handle that detail in the cipher suite list string.

---

For completeness, you should also use the following cipher list string with [`SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html):

```
HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!RC4:!MD5
```

Also see [Obsolete cryptography warning from Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280742/608639) for details.

---

Eventually, you are probably going to run into more browser troubles. Browsers have moved against self signed server certificates. To solve that, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639).

After fixing the self signed certificate, your server certificate will likely have troubles due to the server name in the Common Name (CN). Server names ***must*** be listed in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN). To fix that, see [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639).