# Why is Java 11 ignoring cipher suite TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384?

Tags: java, ssl

I'm troubleshooting a problem and trying to force a java app to use the Cipher Suite = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

But this is being ignored based on SSL debug handhake logging.  I'll see a message like:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|27|http-bio-8443-exec-1|2023-03-22 15:24:23.221 GMT|
HandshakeContext.java:296|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.2
```

I've placed this single log line on two lines for readability.

My questions are: **What causes Java 11 to ignore this cipher suite? and Is there a way to make it get used?**

### Searching for solution

I found that `openssl` can list ciphers:

```
openssl ciphers -V | grep AES | grep GCM | grep 384
. . . not all shown . . .
  0xC0,0x30 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
  0xC0,0x2C - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
  0x00,0xA5 - DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
  0x00,0x9D - AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
```

I think the last one is the one I'm looking for, so perhaps the syntax I'm using is not correct.

Other SSL questions include:

- [Wrong cipher suite or no connection with OpenSSL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446431/wrong-cipher-suite-or-no-connection-with-openssl-server)

Comment: For hysterical raisins OpenSSL uses ciphersuite names that differ from the standard ones used by Java and some can be misleading. OpenSSL `AES256-GCM-SHA384` is standard `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` (TLS1.2 only) not `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` (TLS1.3 only). See [the man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES).

Answer (score 0):

The cipher suite you've listed is supported in Java 11.
The table at [Java 11 Cipher Suites Supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#jsse-cipher-suite-names) documents the cipher suites supported and `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` is included in that list.

At the end of the log message the string **for TLSv1.2** appears.
This appears because the cipher suite while supported is only supported for **TLSv1.3**, and so it's likely that the SSLManager context that was created or the connection that has been established was negotiated at version *TLSv1.2* (by the server) so that cipher is not supported (in this situation).

To force it to be used, you might try only allowing *TLSv1.3* to see if that fixes the problem and allows that cipher suite to be used.